# Text Value Templates and xsl:variable

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

Creating an error message in a variable, I have noticed a quirk.  I had expected all 3 below examples to work - I'm using Saxon 9.8EE.

This works fine:

```
<xsl:variable name="error" select="'Error reading: ' || $file"/>
```

So does this:

```
<xsl:variable name="error"><text>Error reading: {$file}</text></xsl:variable>
```

But this renders {$file} as a literal string, not the value-of $file:

```
<xsl:variable name="error">Error reading: {$file}</xsl:variable>
```

The use case is in an otherwise block to catch a failed file read:

```
<xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:variable name="error" select="'Error reading: ' || $file"/>
    <xsl:message>{$error}</xsl:message>
    {$error}
</xsl:otherwise>
```

Is the embedded text element mandatory?  Why is this not needed for the message element?

Comment: It's not mandatory, but an empty message is pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. Please watch the bug tracker

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3748

to follow it through to resolution.

For a workaround, add the attribute `as="xs:string"`. In fact, it's probably a good idea to add this anyway, since the variable is almost certainly intended to be used as a string (not as a document node containing a single text node child, which is what you get without the "as" attribute).